# yahoo pipes and custom rss

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I've created a custom yahoo pipe to extract specific events from a web site that I want to deliver by email as a reminder.

I've created duplicate the item.content in different custom fields that are parsed and stripped out of unnecessary things, and by clicking on the Pipe Output, everything is there.

However, when it comes to the RSS output, unfortunately just a few - standard - items are pulled out.

Is there any way to extract also the additional items I created?

Many thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

The RSS feed by definition only has the standard items.  The easiest thing to do is to use the Create RSS module.  Map each of the standard RSS fields to your custom content fields - since you're the only consumer of the RSS, you'll just need to remember that the description field is actually something else.

If you are using the RSS field to feed something else, you could also get the json output which will include all your fields, and read the json to create your email.

Comment: Hi Joel, where is the "Create RSS Module", I can't see it to be honest with you.